# File size of Excel file doesn't change after deleting several worksheets via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, size

I ran a simulation in excel with VBA that gave me back about 200 worksheets and a summary of the simulation data. Now, I recognize that the speed of Excel became slower. Thus, I deletes the bulk of the worksheets that only the worksheet with the summary remains to reduce the file size (which is currently about 140mb). Unfortunately, the file size did not change significantly. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: So, you have deleted 200 worksheets out of 201 and the size did not change? Have you saved the file after deleting?

Comment: What is in your summary sheet? Are there a lot of graphs / tables, whilst the other sheets only have plain data, then there is your problem.

Comment: Yes, I saved the file, I reopened it, I rebooted the computer, I looked in the VBA project tree - the worksheets aren't listed anymore (although the last worksheet still has the name "table206". I deleted about 170 worksheets, 40 worksheets are remaining, however 39 worksheets were there before the simulation and have( together) a size of about 0.5mb. The summary worksheet is a big one. It has about 30 columns and 400k rows, but compared with the deleted worksheets it has not such a big size that the file size would not change. The summary sheet has no graphs or tables

Comment: I saved just the summary worksheet in a new workbook and it's size is 64.5 MB, so with the other 39 worksheets from before the simulation the file size should be 65.0 mb

Comment: Which file format: xls or xlsx? If the latter and the deleted sheets wrote a lot of information to, say, the shared strings and styles xml files, that could account for "bloat". You'd need to inspect the underlying Excel Open XML to analyze this thoroughly.

Comment: It's a xlsm file

Comment: ..... Excel 2007

Comment: What cell do you end up on if you push Ctrl + End in the Summary Sheet? What filesize do you get if you copy the data in the Summary worksheet, and Paste Special into a new workbook and save?

Comment: I end at row 399180, so the last row with data. Not ending at the end of the sheet at 1kk. So, no difference between the original workbook and the new created one.

Answer (score 0):

When I run my similar scenario - I am unable to duplicate your issue.   How are you deleting the sheets?  This is what I use to delete the extra sheets and the file size is modified correctly when I save.

```
Sub DeleteSheets1()
'This macro will delete all sheets except 'sheet1'
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I did it quite similar:    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Left(Sheet.Name,10) = "Simulation" Then
            Sheet.Delete
        End If
    Next Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Hit Ctrl+Shift+End and confirm the selected area.  Is it what you expect or does the range extend far beyond what you expect?  Select all columns to the right of what you don't want/need, and delete this range.  Select all rows down from the spot you need to preserve, and delete this range.  Save your file.  Check the size.  Is this what you expect to see?

Also, use this VBA script below to recalculate the used range for each sheet.

```
Sub ExcelDiet() 

    Dim j               As Long 
    Dim k               As Long 
    Dim LastRow         As Long 
    Dim LastCol         As Long 
    Dim ColFormula      As Range 
    Dim RowFormula      As Range 
    Dim ColValue        As Range 
    Dim RowValue        As Range 
    Dim Shp             As Shape 
    Dim ws              As Worksheet 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

    On Error Resume Next 

    For Each ws In Worksheets 
        With ws 
             'Find the last used cell with a formula and value
             'Search by Columns and Rows
            On Error Resume Next 
            Set ColFormula = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            Set ColValue = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            Set RowFormula = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            Set RowValue = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            On Error GoTo 0 

             'Determine the last column
            If ColFormula Is Nothing Then 
                LastCol = 0 
            Else 
                LastCol = ColFormula.Column 
            End If 
            If Not ColValue Is Nothing Then 
                LastCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastCol, ColValue.Column) 
            End If 

             'Determine the last row
            If RowFormula Is Nothing Then 
                LastRow = 0 
            Else 
                LastRow = RowFormula.Row 
            End If 
            If Not RowValue Is Nothing Then 
                LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastRow, RowValue.Row) 
            End If 

             'Determine if any shapes are beyond the last row and last column
            For Each Shp In .Shapes 
                j = 0 
                k = 0 
                On Error Resume Next 
                j = Shp.TopLeftCell.Row 
                k = Shp.TopLeftCell.Column 
                On Error GoTo 0 
                If j > 0 And k > 0 Then 
                    Do Until .Cells(j, k).Top > Shp.Top + Shp.Height 
                        j = j + 1 
                    Loop 
                    If j > LastRow Then 
                        LastRow = j 
                    End If 
                    Do Until .Cells(j, k).Left > Shp.Left + Shp.Width 
                        k = k + 1 
                    Loop 
                    If k > LastCol Then 
                        LastCol = k 
                    End If 
                End If 
            Next 

            .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol + 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete 
            .Range("A" & LastRow + 1 & ":A" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete 
        End With 
    Next 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 

End Sub
```